# meteor 0.9.2 update breaks app

Tags: meteor

Just updated to meteor 0.9.2 from 0.9.1 and my app seems to have stop working.  I'm running it in the development default server at localhost:3000 and nothing is showing up in the browser, even though my server is running fine.  I figured I'd rollback to my previous version but my smart.json and smart.lock doesn't show a version number for me to change.  I'm stumped. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure,try to run `meteor run -p 0.0.0.0:3000` I think,ateast for me, it is not running on default port,try to give the port number

Comment: hmm. gave it a try but no dice. Thanks anyway.

Comment: iAnME's comment has resolved it for me.  Incidently you can rollback to 0.9.1 using:
meteor update --release 0.9.1

Comment: Known issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2596

Comment: ah great.  I'll make a note of that. thanks

Comment: Thanks @iAmME - `meteor run -p 0.0.0.0:3000` saves the day! (I am testing on mobile devices and need access to dev via IP)

Answer (score 2):

remove iron-router version 8.2 and reinstall by running        meteor add iron:router